# "operation is not allowed when the object is closed" in adodc visual basic 6

Tags: listview, vb6, basic

Hey guys my friend told me to ask questions here, I'm new here so i really hope you guys can help me with this big problem of our thesis.

So a message box always appear saying "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed", it always appears when i delete all of listed items in my database table, but when i press OK i works even though the its an error. I tried to explain it to my prof about what is going on and she said that we should really find a way to remove it, i tried everything, i search in microsoft support and in other web still no answer. so I really do hope you guys can help me please.

here is the code of my Delete all listed items in vb6. by the way i use listview and adodc and that is the only component our teacher told us to use not adodb or datagrid just adodc and listview.

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

txtqty.Text = "1"
On Error Resume Next
confirm = MsgBox("Do you really want to Delete all record?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Warning!")
If confirm = vbYes Then

Adodc1.RecordSource = "DELETE * FROM tblbill"
Adodc1.Refresh
Adodc1.Recordset.Delete

MsgBox "Records Successfully Deleted", , "Deleted"
lv2.ListItems.Clear
Adodc1.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblbill"
Adodc1.Refresh
For X = 1 To Adodc1.Recordset.RecordCount
lv2.ListItems.Add , , Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(0)
lv2.ListItems(X).SubItems(1) = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(1)
lv2.ListItems(X).SubItems(2) = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(2)
lv2.ListItems(X).SubItems(3) = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(3)
Adodc1.Recordset.MoveNext
Next
txtcash.Text = ""
Text5.Enabled = True
Text5.Text = ""
Text5.Enabled = False
txtchange.Text = ""
cmddel.Enabled = False
Command2.Enabled = False
cmdadd.Enabled = False
Else
MsgBox "Records not Deleted.", vbInformation, "Record not Deleted"
End If
End Sub
```

when i remove the adodc1.refresh at the bottom of adodc1.recordsource delete, the message will be gone but my listview is messed up. help me please.the due date of our thesis is tomorrow please help me.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but try changing Adodc1.RecordSource = "DELETE * FROM tblbill" to Adodc1.RecordSource = "SET NOCOUNT ON; DELETE * FROM tblbill"

Comment: well still not working, a new message box appeared saying

    "Invalid SQL Statement; Expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."

Comment: I realize that this post is two and a half years old, but this is a perfect example of why you should always avoid `On Error Resume Next`  This would likely be solvable if you could see if and what other error is occurring in the code.  Errors should be handled, not ignored.